# Numpy MemoryError

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

I am stacking a huge amount of rasters to calculate a median for satellite data of 2 month, this worked fine when the data had a 10m resolution.

Since I am running the same functions on the 20m resolution data (-> raster should be 1/2 of the cols and rows) I get memory errors.

I did not change anything in between but the Bands of the initial satellite data.

I know that there is a huge amount of data as this is both a long time and a lot big spatial extent, but still it worked for smaller resolutions.

I am working on a virtual machine with python3.6 in Anaconda, the machine has 128 GB RAM and 16 VCPus.

The error messages:

```
<class 'numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError'>, ((563, 256, 55296), dtype('int64')) -> always
<class 'MemoryError'>, ((506, 256, 54528), dtype('bool')) -> sometimes
```

Below is the merging-code, where file_list is the link:

```
import os

from typing import List
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import glob


def build_vrt(vrt: str, files: List[str], resample_name: str) -> None:
    """builds .vrt file which will hold information needed for overlay
    Args:
        vrt (:obj:`string`): name of vrt file, which will be created
        files (:obj:`list`): list of file names for merging
        resample_name (:obj:`string`): name of resampling method
    """

    options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(srcNodata=-9999)
    gdal.BuildVRT(destName=vrt, srcDSOrSrcDSTab=files, options=options)
    add_pixel_fn(vrt, resample_name)


def add_pixel_fn(filename: str, resample_name: str) -> None:
    """inserts pixel-function into vrt file named 'filename'
    Args:
        filename (:obj:`string`): name of file, into which the function will be inserted
        resample_name (:obj:`string`): name of resampling method
    """

    header = """  <VRTRasterBand dataType="uInt16" band="1" subClass="VRTDerivedRasterBand">"""
    contents = """
    <PixelFunctionType>{0}</PixelFunctionType>
    <PixelFunctionLanguage>Python</PixelFunctionLanguage>
    <PixelFunctionCode><![CDATA[{1}]]>
    </PixelFunctionCode>"""

    lines = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
    lines[3] = header  # FIX ME: 3 is a hand constant
    lines.insert(4, contents.format(resample_name,
                                    get_resample(resample_name)))
    open(filename, 'w').write("".join(lines))


def get_resample(name: str) -> str:
    """retrieves code for resampling method
    Args:
        name (:obj:`string`): name of resampling method
    Returns:
        method :obj:`string`: code of resample method
    """

    methods = {
        "median":
        """
import numpy as np
    def median(in_ar, out_ar, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, raster_xsize,raster_ysize, buf_radius, gt, **kwargs):
        div = np.zeros((len(in_ar),in_ar[0].shape[0],in_ar[0].shape[1]), dtype=np.float16)
        for i in range(len(in_ar)):
            div[i,:,:] = np.where(in_ar[i] != 0,in_ar[i],np.nan)

        y = np.nanmedian(div, axis=0)

        np.clip(y,y.min(),y.max(), out = out_ar)
"""}

if name not in methods:
    raise ValueError(
        "ERROR: Unrecognized resampling method (see documentation): '{}'.".
        format(name))

return methods[name]


def merge(files: List[str], output_file: str, resample: str = "average") -> None:
    """merges list of files using specific resample method for overlapping parts
    Args:
        files (:obj:`list[string]`): list of files to merge
        output_file (:obj:`string`): name of output file
        resample (:obj:`string`): name of resampling method
    """
    #des=r"E:\naser\code_de\output\test\_vrt.vrt"
    des=os.getcwd() + "/_vrt.vrt"
    print("1")
    build_vrt(des, files, resample)
    print("2")
    gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_VRT_ENABLE_PYTHON', 'YES')
    print("3")
    translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine("-of Gtiff -ot UINT16 -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW BIGTIFF=YES NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -a_nodata 0"))
    gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_CACHEMAX","512")
    gdal.Translate(destName=output_file, srcDS=des, options=translateoptions)
    print("4")
    gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_VRT_ENABLE_PYTHON', None)
    print("5")
    if os.path.isfile(des):
        os.remove(des)



def mergeAll(file_list,Outname,resample):
    merge(file_list,Outname,resample)
```

Is there a reasonable explanation as to why this is happening the way it happens? Or what I can do?

Comment: An int64 array of shape (563, 256, 55296) requires already 60 GB of memory. If you have another such an array, you've already nearly exhausted your memory, so double check how many large arrays you have.

Comment: Thats a good point, I will have to check that again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are surpassing the available amount of memory in your virtual machine.

A workaround  might be trying [to increase it](https://enterprise-docs.anaconda.com/en/latest/admin/resources/resource-profile.html). Or redesign your program to work in chunks (batch processing), so you access to your data in batches instead of loading all the files into memory.